# How to restore tensorflow model without index file and meta file?

Tags: python, tensorflow

New checkpoint format generates three files: `model.ckpt-1000.data-00000-of-00001`,`model.ckpt-1000.meta`,`model.ckpt-1000.index`. Old checkpoint format only generates two files: `model.ckpt-1000` and `model.ckpt-1000.meta`.

When I restore model wrote with new checkpoint format using code `saver.restore(sess, './model.ckpt-1000')`, it can restore model successfully. Now current directory has three files `model.ckpt-1000.data-00000-of-00001`, `model.ckpt-1000.meta`, `model.ckpt-1000.index`. If I delete `model.ckpt-1000.index`, it cannot restore model. Error information:`DataLossError (see above for traceback): Unable to open table file ./model.ckpt-1000: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?`.

But I notice tensorflow [pretrained model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim#pre-trained-models) that only has one file: `*.ckpt`. When I use pretrained model provided by tensorflow, it can restore sucessfully. It does not need `*.index` file.

My tensorflow version is 1.1.0.

How did it save model? Did it use old checkpoint format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it did use the old checkpoint format. Here's a simple example I used to verify:

```
import tensorflow as tf

slim = tf.contrib.slim

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 16])
y = slim.fully_connected(x, 4)

saver_v1 = tf.train.Saver(write_version=tf.train.SaverDef.V1)

saver_v2 = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    saver_v1.save(sess, 'model_v1.ckpt',
                  write_meta_graph=False,
                  write_state=False)

    saver_v2.save(sess, 'model_v2.ckpt',
                  write_meta_graph=False,
                  write_state=False)
```

The results of `ls model*` after running the script:

```
model_v1.ckpt  model_v2.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001  model_v2.ckpt.index
```